# iPhone browser that supports web workers?

Tags: javascript, iphone, multithreading, browser, web-worker

Came to realize that iphone's safari browser does not support javascript web workers (multithreading). Am wondering whether there is another browser for iphone that does support this feature.

(i do not own an iphone, so i cannot just download and try all available browsers)

Comment: Can you rephrase your question into a specific one about programming? If not, then SO isn't the right place for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you're not likely to find an alternative browser that supports web workers now (pretty much all the alternative browsers for iOS use Safari's engine underneath, due to restrictions on code execution), reports indicate that web worker support is going to be in Safari for iOS 5.  See:

http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/new-mobile-safari-stuff-in-ios5-position-fixed-overflow-scroll-new-input-type-support-web-workers-ecmascript-5 (about halfway down the page)